# ASP.NET redirect between three web sites

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, response.redirect, http-redirect

Let's say for example that my site is `www.mysite.com`.

I have create a sub domain here, let's say `sub.mysite.com`, and deployed an asp.net webform application in here. Everything works fine when I browse to `http://sub.mysite.com`

A friend of mine, who owns another website, let's say `www.hissite.com`, has created a DNS entry for the subdomain `sub.hissite.com` and setup the IP address of my web site. He want to redirect the subdomain of his web site to the subdomain of my website.

Unfortunately my provider told me that this kind of configuration works only for 2nd level domains and that I should create a piece of code, in my `www.mysite.com` web application, to check if the request is relative to the site `sub.hissite.com`, and do a redirect in that case to my `sub.mysite.com`.

How do I check if the request is for `sub.hissite.com` in my webform application?
What happens to the URL in the client browser?

Thanks for help

**EDIT 1**:
Actually I have configured an alias for my website but I get the following error when navigating to `sub.hissite.com`:

```
Application Request Routing Error 
500 - Internal server error. 
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. The domain may not be inserted correctly on Rewrite Maps.
```

**EDIT 2**:
Following the answer of [OnoSendai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20569636/431537) I have implemented an MVC ActionFilter

```
public class MyRedirectFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext filterContext ) {
        string newUri = "http://sub.mysite.com";
        HttpRequestBase request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        string referer = request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]; 
        if ( referer != null && referer.Contains( "hissite" ) ) {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect( newUri, true );
        }
    }
}
```

And now the application works nice. However the address in the browser address bar change from `www.hissite.com` to `sub.mysite.com`. Is there any way to make it not change?
Thanks

Comment: you can configure iis to respond to that subdomain also

Comment: Do you mean by using aliases?

Comment: using bindings and hostname http://serverfault.com/questions/26166/how-to-create-a-subdomain-in-iis7

Comment: Yes. You're right. But unfortunately I cant direct access IIS settings because it is a shared hosting. The only thing I can do is to set an alias which in turn translate into an IIS binding. However this is not enough because the binding alone can not distinguish between the domain and the subdomain.

Comment: you could use urlrewrite module

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? Is it a code solution?

Comment: @Lorenzo: May be you can use [ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx). But not sure in this case

Comment: @Lorenzo just curious, how did you solve?

Comment: @giammin: hello giammin, I have implemented both the solutions suggested here. Unfortunately still had no time to test them. I think I am going to upload the new version in the nxt two days and I'll let you know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what your ISP told you is that you'll need to do the check and redirect yourself.

One way to do that programatically is to check the `HTTP_REFERER` header, using `Request.UrlReferrer` or a direct reference via Request.ServerVariables - something like this:

```
if (Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST") == "sub.hissite.com/page1.aspx")
    Response.Redirect("sub.mysite.com/page1.aspx");
```

Now you may be thinking, '*but wait - I'll have to implement this on all pages?*'

Oh, heavens, no! You may try to bundle this check inside a neat HttpModule. That'll allow you to intercept all requests (including resource requests such as jpg, js and css files) and decide what to do - which is, basically, what the UrlRewrite module does.

A very simple and neat post about HttpModules can be found here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alikl/archive/2007/12/26/basic-httpmodule-sample-plus-bonus-case-study-how-httomodule-saved-mission-critical-project-s-life.aspx

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I have implemented your solution, with some small changes, in form of a MVC ActionFilter (I forgot to mention that it was MVC). Please have a look at my edit for a further clarification. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad it worked for you! About the URL - the only way I know of to preserve the URL is to open a Frame (or IFrame) on his website and point the frame's source property to your page instead. You can't use server.execute since you're on different servers.

Answer (score 2):

The easier way would be to [configure IIS to point to your site for that kind of request](https://serverfault.com/questions/26166/how-to-create-a-subdomain-in-iis7) but as you say in comments you can't because you are in a shared hosting without access to IIS.

Than an easy solution could be to Use [Asp.net Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx).
Anyway you need the [routing module to be installed on server](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing).

In web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
...
<rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite subdomains">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
             <!--take all request for any subdomain of hissite.com-->
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.+)\.hissite\.com$"  ignoreCase="true"/>
        </conditions>
        <!--rewrite request as sub.mysite.com-->
        <action type="Rewrite" url="http://sub.mysite.com/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
</system.webServer>
```

**I cannot test this so maybe you need to adjust to your needs.**

Comment: Wow! this seems very easy. should I put this in `web.config` of `mysite.com`?

Comment: @Lorenzo yes in  system.webServer  section

Comment: this was the best solution for me. However, unfortunately my ISP does not have the routing module installed.. Thanks very much for your answer, I learned a lot from this. :)